# Set default value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using html textarea to get my arrays and i am
trying to display $name x number of times and if x isn't specified it should display it one time.

Here is my code so far:

```
    $str = $_POST['text'];
    $input = explode("\n", $str);
    foreach($input as $line){
    $line1 = explode(' ', $line);
    $number = $line1[0];
    $name = ltrim($line, $number.' ');
    $number = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $number);
    $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $name);
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $number ; $i++ )
    {
        echo $name;
    }}
```

Appreciate your help

edit:

Example (this goes to textarea which i get via post method)

```
    2x Blue Flower
    3 Red Flower
    1 Orange Flower
    Green Flower
```

Now it shows it like this (this is the result of my code)

```
Blue Flower 
Blue Flower 
Red Flower
Red Flower 
Red Flower 
Orange Flower
```

As you can see it doesn't show Green Flower.

Comment: check if $number is empty then set it to 1

Comment: I've tried it in a few different ways but with no success.

Comment: do you want to set $number=1 if it is empty?

Comment: Yes, $number should be 1 if empty. I've tried setting default values in array without luck :(

Answer (score 0):

try replace last rows to:

```
$number = intval( preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $number) );
if ( $number < 1 ) $number = 1;
$name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $name);
echo str_repeat($name, $number);
```

Comment: not working, it does the same as mine, it shows everything right except when there is no number next to name (the name with no number isn't shown)

Comment: Please explain more about _"there is no number next to name (the name with no number isn't shown)"_.
Show examples

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $number ; $i++ )
{
    echo $name;
}
```

With:

```
echo $number . ' - ' . $name;
```

If that doesn't work can you post the actual content of `$_POST['text']`

Comment: sure, i am very sorry if i wasn't clear enough.
This doesn't work as i need it to work. As it says in my question, $_POST['text'] is taken from textarea. In my example first thing written is the text that users put in textarea and the second thing is what the code currently does. I will edit it to say that.